# FTPS connection with SFTP/FTP Sublime Text plugin

Tags: sublimetext, ftp-client, ftps

Can I use Sublime SFTP plugin ([from here](https://wbond.net/sublime_packages/sftp)) to make an FTPS connection type?

I was previously working with Notepad++ and the NppFTP plugin but I want to migrate towards Sublime Text however I have problems using the SFTP plugin to connect to my server. Here is my configuration file:

```
"type": "ftps",
"sync_down_on_open": true,
"sync_same_age": true,
"host": "xxxxxxxxxxxxx.org",
"user": "xxxxx@xxxxxxxxxxxxx.org",
"password": "xxxxx",
"port": "21",
"remote_path": "/home/xxxxxxxx/public_html",
"connect_timeout": 30,
```

I've been trying to change the remote_path multiple times and I can't make it work. I've been getting this error:

> Connecting to FTPS server "xxxxxxxxxxxxx.org" as "xxxxx@xxxxxxxxxxxxx.org" .... success
>   Validating remote folder "/home/xxxxxxxx/public_html" .. failure (Folder not found)
>   Multiple disconnection errors, giving up

In my Cpanel, the path for all the FTP users is set to /home/cpanel_username/public_html.

I've also tried setting remove_path to "/" and I get another error:

> Validating remote folder "/" .... failure (Disconnected)

Any ideas how I can make it work?

Answer (score 6):

If your control panel has already specified the path for FTP connection then your remote path should just be '/'. Otherwise you are likely attempting to access:

/home/xxxxxxxx/public_html/home/xxxxxxxx/public_html

If you've tested '/' and that still doesn't work, possibly attempt connecting with an interactive FTPS client so you can see the root folder structure?

Comment: This just saved my day. For those having the same problem try the answer above and then just try to browse the remote. If it was successful you will be able to browse your files in the sublime popup window.

Comment: I changed the type to `ftp` and it worked. Changed back to `ftps` and it also worked.

Answer (score 2):

I've been having this error today, totally out of the blue because I use Sublime's SFTP package daily.

I closed Sublime and reopened it... problem solved.

Comment: YOU ARE A LEGEND... + 1

Answer (score 2):

I encountered this error message when I had the wrong setting on the `ftp_passive_mode`. Just commenting it solved my problem.

[image: commented ftp_passive_mode setting picture]

Other (common) situations & errors that I've encountered were:

- wrong server type: [image: server type setting picture] which gave the following error: [image: wrong server type setting error picture]
- no port setting: [image: no port setting picture] which (weirdly) gave the following error: [image: no port setting error picture]
- wrong port setting: [image: wrong port setting picture] which gave the following error: [image: wrong port setting error picture]

I really hope these basic list helps people.

Answer (score 1):

Changed type to `ftp` even though it really SHOULD be `ftps` and it worked.

Comment: Did not work for me. I have explicit FTPS set on the server and it failed with "Server requires FTPS connection"

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem while **my local folder was inside OneDrive** (I am using Windows 10). When I **changed** the location of the local folder **to /Documents**/someFolder it worked properly!

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the `ftp.`
It worked for me like a charm

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I faced this error when I copied sftp config file to another pc and tried to connect in that pc. Restarting PC did not work and then I deleted that sftp config file and created new one with the same configuration and the it worked

Answer (score 0):

If someone having problem with IP address as a host. I got it working by using only ip address without trailing slash "/".

```
127.0.0.1
```

Answer (score 0):

// sftp, ftp or ftps
    "type": "ftps",

Change type as **ftps** and then also look for your root folder as you have defined while creating the ftp account.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to know the paths that you have set up for FTP and not your local computer but the path to the directory you want to download on the server you want to connect to. ie: home/public_html/images or something.

Answer (score 0):

For debugging, i suggest go to **Preferences / Package Settings / SFTP / Settings**

then add the lines

**{
"debug": 2
,"debug_log_file": "/home/**YOURUSER**/sublime_sftp_debug.txt"
}**

My problem was that the ftp credantials gave only read access to **/**, so i changed **remote_path** to **/web**

now you can see error logs in "/home/**YOURUSER**/sublime_sftp_debug.txt"

Answer (score 0):

// sftp, ftp or ftps
**"type": "ftps",**

Use FTPS Worked like a charm for me.
No need to do changes in this lines

//"ftp_passive_mode": true,
//"ftp_obey_passive_host": false,
//"ssh_key_file": "~/.ssh/id_rsa",

Let them commented

Answer (score 0):

For me, it worked by explicitly setting `ftp_passive_mode` to `false`. The line was commented out (with `//`). SFTP was unable to Validate Remote Folder, although Connection to FTP server was successful. So tried explicitly set `ftp_passive_mode` to `false` and behold IT WORKED!!!.

Hope helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

Same thing happened to me but only when I changed router. Going to the firewall settings on the router and the Security-ALG section, I removed the "FTP ALG" option from the list and then everything worked fine.